# State management in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to show a Session Variable data on View.
How can i achieve it.
I am storing some data in Session varaibles and noew i want to display it on View please help me.

I am new Asp.Net MVC 2

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the ViewData and pass it to the view

in your controller set up something like ViewData["namehere"] = value

then in your View you can call the value of Viewdata["name here"] - think of the ViewData as a bag that you can put properties and their values into and not need to explicitly pass the viewdata to the view for the view to use it

Answer (score 0):

view data is just like session in asp.net so in your controller you can create more than one view data then create you view ,if you want to create a partial control for the view it will alse see the result of the view data but do not forget to cast the result.